# Compare columns of csv and txt file and update csv file with same entries that matches in both doc using bash script

Tags: bash, csv

Can any one help me with this task to
Compare columns of csv and txt file and update csv file with same entries that matches in both doc using bash script

file1.csv

```
tiger roar 12 7869 
dog bark 6 4455
cat mew 8 4432
puppy bark 2 4455
```

and so on...

file2.txt

```
7869 ability1
4455 abilityX
4455 ability2
4432 ability3
8899 ability4
```

and so on...

we need to match 4th column of csv file and 1st column of txt file and for same entries update 2nd column in csv file.

expected output

```
tiger roar 12 7869 ability1 
dog bark 6 4455 ability2 abilityX
cat mew 8 4432ability3
puppy bark 2 4455 ability2 abilityX
```

and so on...

if any one has any idea how we can make this possible in bash and python...

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please show what you tried up to now and explain why it did not work as expected.

Comment: Why is this tagged CSV? Neither of the files involved look as if they were CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk \
'if (FNR==NR) {
    ability[$1] = ability[$1]" "$2
}
else {
    print $0 ability[$4]
}' abilities.txt animals.csv > animals-updated.csv
```

Your “csv” file (comma separated variables) doesn’t actually contain commas (`,`). If it did, you could add `FS=","` directly above `print`.